# Understanding the arguments to function of PyMC3

Tags: python, numpy, bayesian, pymc3

I ran into this piece of code:

```
data = np.repeat((0, 1), (3, 6))
with pm.Model() as normal_approximation:
    p = pm.Uniform('p', 0, 1)
    w = pm.Binomial('w', n=len(data), p=p, observed=data.sum())
    mean_q = pm.find_MAP() # MAP: maximum a posteriori probability
    std_q = ((1/pm.find_hessian(mean_q, vars=[p]))**0.5)[0]
mean_q['p'], std_q
```

I tried to search google generally and look at the documentation at what is the argument `observed` for `pm.Binomial` and what is the function `find_hessian` (for example what's the meaning of the `vars` keyword) - but I see no explanation.

can someone not only explain these questions to me, but refer me to the right source to answer such questions myself?

Comment: what documentation did you find?

Comment: nothing relevant, that's the issue

Comment: So you didn't find the documentation at https://docs.pymc.io?

Comment: I did, but as far as I can tell - it is incomplete and missing the info I'm after

Comment: When I asked what docs you found, I was expecting you to give the link that I posted in my answer below or something similar. That page is highly relevant, just missing the details that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generally recommend reading through the tutorials, especially the ["API Quick Start"](https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/pymc-examples/examples/pymc3_howto/api_quickstart.html) and ["Getting Started"](https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/pymc-examples/examples/getting_started.html) ones. They'll cover the basics of how PyMC3 builds a graphical model of RandomVariables as a compute graph, including what `observed` RVs are (i.e., the ones you have observed and therefore have data from which a likelihood can be evaluated). Unless one already has a strong background in Bayesian inference, learning through examples will likely be the most effective route.

Otherwise, keep [the API](https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api.html) at hand, and make use of Python's `help` function.

For example, you can get the signature of `find_hessian` with the latter:

```python
> help(pm.find_hessian)
find_hessian(point, vars=None, model=None)
    Returns Hessian of logp at the point passed.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    model: Model (optional if in `with` context)
    point: dict
    vars: list
        Variables for which Hessian is to be calculated.
```

This particular method is more of an internal utility (e.g., it gets used by NUTS sampler), but those with a math-stats or physics background (such as the person who wrote the original code) will recognize it as the matrix of second partials, and understand its relationship to the covariance matrix. In the particular code, it is evaluating the `p` variable at the MAP location (`mean_q`), and then this is converted to the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api/distributions/discrete.html#pymc3.distributions.discrete.Binomial describes `n` and `p` parameters, but doesn't list `observed`. After digging into the [source code](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc), I found that [`Binomial`](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/main/pymc/distributions/discrete.py#L68) inherits from [a class named `Distribution`](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/main/pymc/distributions/distribution.py#L137-L189) which declares the `observed` parameter:

> observed : optional
>
> Observed data to be passed when registering the random variable in the model.
>
> See `Model.register_rv`.

Comment: I don't think it get's ignored, I've seen the argument in many different examples. I wonder if there's a way to test it.

Comment: @MoranReznik What is the output `w`? The other option is that anything other than `n` and `p` are just passed on as is to the output.

Comment: @MoranReznik To answer my question, it looks like `w` is an instance of the `Binomial` class. What do you get if you `print(w.observed)`. Or `print(dict(w))` might also give some clues as to how `observed` is used.

Comment: both return an error :/

Comment: @MoranReznik Sorry, the second one should be `dir(w)`, not `dict(w)`.

Comment: @MoranReznik Notice that the example at https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api/distributions/discrete-3.py does not have `observed`, so at the very least it is optional.

Comment: @MoranReznik See my updated answer with some additional details I found.

Comment: ty, that comes close to a full answer.

Comment: @MoranReznik I'm unfamiliar with pymc3. I'm just leveraging my general knowledge of Python and statistics to help track down the details you are asking about. I don't know what "registering the random variable in the model" means, but hopefully this points you in the direction you need. At this point, if you aren't registering anything, then `observed` is meaningless and probably should just be left out.

Comment: @MoranReznik ...and I just stumbled across https://docs.pymc.io/en/latest/api/distributions/utilities.html which is the documentation rendered from the source code I linked in my answer.

Comment: @MoranReznik https://docs.pymc.io/en/latest/api/model.html#pymc.model.Model.register_rv It looks like you can alternatively pass the observed data as `data` to `Model.register_rv()`.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, friend. hopefully, someone who is familiar with PyMC3 will show up and help out.